# angular2 access ngModel variable from a directive

Tags: angular, directive, angular2-ngmodel

I am trying to build a datetime picker directive like the following.
`<input [(ngModel)]="date1" datetime-picker date-only />`

and `date1` is assigned as a Date, e.g., `new Date()`

When I display this in html, text in input element looks like the following
`Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500`

I want to display like the following instead
`2015-01-01 00:00:00`

I want to format date WITHIN a directive using DatePipe instead of showing result from default toString() function.

My question is; "within a directive, how do I access ngModel variable?", e.g., date1, so that I can add toString() method.

If my approach is not right, please advise me.

Comment: doesn't angular pass the model value to your `transform` function of your pipe?

Answer (score 20):

Here is simple and easy way to listen and notify ngModel. I have just demonstrated with jQuery for easy understanding. Practically, it can be anything.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: `[ngModel][customDir]`,
    providers: [NgModel]
})
export class CustomDirective {


    constructor(private element: ElementRef, private ngModel: NgModel) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let that = this;
        /* Here you can write custom initialization code */

        /* Listening to the value of ngModel */
        that.ngModel.valueChanges.subscribe(function (value) {
            /* Set any value of your custom control */
            $(that.element.nativeElement).data("newValue",value);
        });

        /* Inform ng model for any new change happened */
        $(that.element.nativeElement).bind("customEvent",function (someNewValue) {
                that.ngModel.update.emit(someNewValue);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Dhrumil Bhankar, why 

$(that.element.nativeElement).bind("customEvent",function (someNewValue) {
                that.ngModel.update.emit(someNewValue);
            }
        }); isn't fired in my code

Comment: @gentos Please note that this is generic example. Not actual code. Here "customElement" can be any event. If you want model to update on click you should use "click" instead of that "customEvent" word.

Comment: For this example to work with Angular Ivy (> v9), the line `providers: [NgModel]` should be removed

Answer (score 14):

For accessing `ngModel`, you can simply just have an `@Input()` in your `datetime-picker`. And since you are using 2-way data binding, you have to emit the changes you make to `ngModel`.

```
@Directive({
  selector:'[date-time-picker]'
})
export class DateTimePicker{
  @Input() ngModel;
  @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit(){
    this.ngModelChange.emit(this.ngModel.toDateString());
  }
}
```

[Check this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNelLRAGldqkN5Oq4MO2?p=preview)

---

The better way IMHO, is using the [`DatePipe`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-class.html)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives:[DateTimePicker],
  template: `
      <input (ngModelChange)="myDate = $event" [ngModel]="myDate | date:'short'" datetime-picker  />
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  myDate = new Date();
}
```

[Check this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/A6AwBk9AcYXZoG9dfnYU?p=preview)

Comment: This solution is good to display date in format. However, it does not change a method, `toString`, of a ngModel, which actually does the formatting of a date. It actually change an ngModel from `Date` to `string`, which I do not intend to do. @Abdulrahman, do we need to emit a new ngModel with toString modified?

Comment: @allenhwkim I see , so you want to override the method `toString()` ? If so, you need to override the method of `Date` not `ngModel`

Comment: No, I do not want to override `Date.toString`. I want to override `toString` method of a Date instance, which is a ngModel.

Comment: `ngOnInit(): void {
    // emit toString Modified(date formatted) instance
    let newNgModel = new Date(this.ngModel.toString());
    newNgModel.toString = () => {
      return new DatePipe().transform(this.ngModel, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    };
    this.ngModelChange.emit(newNgModel);
}` Although this works, I am not sure it has its own cons.

Comment: Alright, I think I got it :D. For that, you need a custom value accessor [check this post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3092-creating-an-abstract-value-accessor-for-ngmodel-in-angular-2-beta-17.htm). In particular,  the method `writeValue`.  Sorry I am writing from my phone.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "keyup" and "this.ngModel.model"

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][customDir]',
  providers: [NgModel]
})
export class CustomDirective {

  constructor(private ngModel: NgModel) { }

  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyUp(event) {
    let value = this.ngModel.model;
    this.ngModel.update.emit(value);
  }
}
```