# Angular 5 template driven Decimal input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, directive

I'm working with Angular 5 template driven forms, and have several numeric inputs in a form.

The requirement I have is very simple, and I'm astounded that I can't find a solution to it

Basically each numeric input should display as a decimal with thousand separators and a configurable number of decimal places, but store the value as a number (without commas) on the model.

I've looked at pipes which aren't applicable as they are display only and do not work with two way binding
I've also searched high and low for an example of a directive that does this by exposing the NgModel of the control and manipulates its data and no joy there either..

I've looked at the one way binding + a setter in the TypeScript but that is ugly and not reusable

```
<input type="number" [NgModel]="somevalue | number : '2.2-6'" (ngModelChange)="somevalue = formatNumber($event)"
```

Can you point me in the right direction? 
I think the directive is the way to go but I can't find a clear example of how to go about separating the input binding from the displaying, and importantly displaying the right value on load if the data is already populated in the model

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This article](https://blog.ngconsultant.io/custom-input-formatting-with-simple-directives-for-angular-2-ec792082976) may help.

Comment: if you just want to display commas in view and save numeric value without commas then what's the problem with using pipe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4899523/abdul-rafay

Pipe doesn't work with two way binding, so you have to break out the bindings as I've shown in the question. Its ugly, and you have to have data converter functions in every component that needs to use decimal inputs. 

I'm looking for something that does this with markup + Directive(?) only without cluttering components with helper stuff that should be written once

Comment: Jeto, that is very very close to what I need.
The only part that is missing is that it is truncating the value on the model if the user enters a value with 3 dps, which could be a valid case, they just want to see to 2dps for clarity (I'll likely have a mouseover that shows the full amount with no truncation) 

I'll play with it some more

Answer (score 1):

Jeto gave me 90% of the solution, and with a couple of tweaks, managed to get the exact behaviour I was after

I followed [This article](https://blog.ngconsultant.io/custom-input-formatting-with-simple-directives-for-angular-2-ec792082976) and got to a state where the field was displaying correctly, but it was always showing the truncated value. 
What I really wanted was a pure "mask" so that the user could give more than 2dps, but would only see 2dps for clarity and have a mouseover to show the entire figure.

I then used [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381882/angular2-access-ngmodel-variable-from-a-directive) to expose the NgModel in the directive so that on focus, the raw value of the ngModel.viewmodel was shown instead of the truncated value

My directive now looks like this (minus the pipe for clarity. Its a cut and paste of the 1st article at the moment)

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { NgModel } from "@angular/forms";
import { DecimalPipe } from "./decimal-pipe";


    @Directive({
        selector: "[decimalFormatter][ngModel]",
        providers: [NgModel]
    })
    export class DecimalFormatterDirective implements OnInit {

        private el: HTMLInputElement;
        @Input('decimals') decimals: number;

        constructor(
            private elementRef: ElementRef,
            private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe,
            private ngModel: NgModel
        ) {
            this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        }

        ngOnInit() {

            if (this.decimals == null)
                this.decimals = 2;

            console.log(this.el);
            console.log(this.ngModel);

            this.el.value = this.decimalPipe.transform(this.el.value, this.decimals);
        }

        @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
        onFocus(value) {
            console.log(this.el);
            console.log(this.ngModel);
            this.el.value = this.ngModel.viewModel; // opossite of transform
        }

        @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
        onBlur(value) {
            console.log(this.el);
            console.log(this.ngModel);
            this.el.value = this.decimalPipe.transform(value, this.decimals);
        }

    }
```

EDIT: Small update

I changed the pipe it was calling from the one in the first article to the actual number pipe that the Angular uses so its now more of a wrapper for the Angular pipe that works with two way binding. 
You also get to pass in the angular number formatting style, for example 2.2-6

Hopefully this helps someone coming across the same issue in the future!

The Directive :

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { NgModel } from "@angular/forms";
import { DecimalFormatPipe } from "./decimal-format-pipe";


    @Directive({
        selector: "[decimalFormatter][ngModel]",
        providers: [NgModel]
    })
    export class DecimalFormatterDirective implements OnInit {

        private el: HTMLInputElement;
        @Input('decimals') decimals: string;

        constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef,
            private ngModel: NgModel,
            private decimalFormatPipe: DecimalFormatPipe) {

            this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

        }

        ngOnInit() {

            if (this.decimals == null)
                this.decimals = "2.0-6";


            console.log(this.el.value, this.decimals);
            this.el.value = this.decimalFormatPipe.transform(this.el.value, this.decimals);
        }

        @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"])
        onFocus(value) {

            console.log(this.el.value, this.decimals);
            this.el.value = this.ngModel.viewModel; //Display the raw value on the model
        }

        @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
        onBlur(value) {

            console.log(this.el.value, this.decimals);
            this.el.value = this.decimalFormatPipe.transform(this.el.value, this.decimals);
        }

    }
```

The Pipe Wrapper

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Inject, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core'
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({ name: 'decimalFormatPipe' })
export class DecimalFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) {}

    transform(value: any, args: string) {
        let pipe = new DecimalPipe(this.locale);
        return pipe.transform(value, args);
    }
}
```

And usage on an Input

```
<input #myNumberInputCtrl="ngModel"
       name="myNumberInput"
       spellcheck="false" 
       placeholder="Enter a Number.." 
       [(ngModel)]="myNumberModel" 
       required 
       decimalFormatter
       [decimals]="'0.0-6'"
 />
```

Comment: thanks for the Implementation. Its very useful in my case. But I have a problem that at ngOnInit the value is "", therefor it is not formatted. Do you also have this issue?